# Web API Design advice

Tags: architecture, asp.net, api-design, web-api

I am developing a Web API as services layer for a ASP.NET web forms application.

There are two controllers `ContractorController` (gives details about the contractor) and `PaymentsController` (gives details about payments done to a contractor).

Now in our UI application we have this User-Control which will be used across many pages:

[image]

Is the responsibility of the UI to call the `ContractorController` and `PaymentsController` separately to get the required data? Or should I provide a Consolidated Method (may be on `PaymentsController`) to give back all the required data, which seems to be going against *RESTful* approach or dealing with resources?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd say this depends fully on the consequences of this decision. Do you have any benefit in building this "consolidated method" (maybe db overhead of doing two calls joining on the contractor, for example) that justifies the time and maintenance (that is, cost) of having an aditional method specifically for this? You might build first having the UI calling separate methods and refactor to a consolidated one later if needed. I would prefer this later strategy, but it all depends on the factors your are facing.

Comment: The only reason I thought of doing a Consolidated Method is that is for performance reasons, which would enable app developer to call Service layer once instead of calling it two times. On second thought we are having some pretty aggressive caching strategy on Contractor Controller, so I guess performance will not be as bad as I thought. We are having lot of scenarios like this, so I wanted to put some serious thought into it before making any decision.

Comment: I would advice against building this new method until the need for it is shown. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". This might have the added benefit of making possible to bring the functionality to a productive state in shorter time.

Comment: @h7r:  That's not what "Premature Optimization" means. Perhaps you're thinking of YAGNI?

Comment: @RobertHarvey YAGNI would fit too. But why do you say it "doesn't mean" that? It means whay it means; you might argue that it does not fit the problem, however I think it does.

Comment: @h7r: Well, first of all, you're not accurately quoting Knuth.  [See here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) for the complete quote.  Premature optimization is about optimizing code to improve its performance, not about adding new features; Knuth was basically saying "Measure your code's performance first, and only optimize the code that will yield useful performance improvements."

Comment: Which ("measuring") is quite in line to what I said. The question, by the way, proposes two ways of addressing the same feature need, one of which might be more optimized. If your point is that based on some puristic assumption the quote should only be applied to some specific instances of optimization (say, unroll a loop, do some asm for specific things, etc), is, imho to miss the broader (and very useful) message the quote conveys (that it might be just good enought as it is, without added complexity). But discussing this will not contribute in any means to the answering the question.

Comment: @h7r Not specific cases of optimization, just performance optimization in general.  Knuth wasn't talking about adding or subtracting features, and the OP didn't ask about performance.

Comment: I'd say all of this can be returned with one call to `/api/contractors/{id}`. A contractor object knows its payments so you're not just aggregating multiple calls.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel But most of the cases when we get Contractor detail we are not bothered about Payments, we just need Contractor Name, address and Phone, It would be an overkill to return list of all payments. Even if I were to return payments with contractors all I need here is last two payments in this case.

Comment: If that is the scenario then yes: make two separate api calls. I would use the `/api/contractors/{id}/payments?limit=2` endpoint for this personally.

Comment: "which seems to be going against RESTful approach or dealing with resources?" you are confusing resources with entities. A resource can consist of many attributes and sub objects containing lists as well. The same way that a view is not restricted to any particular entity. You can structure your resources any way you see fit given the needs of your application. Considering that you plan to use this thing in many places, I would certainly opt for a single resource that pulls everything together for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it this way:

- Encapsulate this UI piece into a component, that is responsible only for UI part of the job. Upon construction this component needs data about both contractor and payments to be provided to it (via constructor, some setter methods - whatever. Depends on your design)
- Encapsulate database-related logic into two services (ContractorService and PaymentService). Those services can fetch data from database using conditions you provide and prepare it (convert types, fill related object instances, localize via calls to LocalizationService etc).
- Now in any controller action (e.g. in any section /page of your website regardless of how controller is called) you first call respected services to fetch the data and then feed this data into your UI component.